# How to design custom EditText without box and with Underline ?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I am developing apps in android. I did design for edittext in my apps see image (default edit text in 4.2.2)

> [image]

I want edittext style like following image

> [image]

Does anybody have solution ?

Comment: you can create a cstom view extend textview. http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/widget/EditText.java/. provide all functionality that editText does by overriding onDraw. look at the link

Comment: Why not stick with the beautiful Holo design language?

Comment: @Raghunandan How can i used it...? and which functionality is ued for this..?

Comment: all you need is to. provide your own background Drawable, no need to extend any class

Comment: @Amardeep by looking at the source modify the same and use a custom view.

Comment: you are right @pskink can i used border in background

Comment: @Amardeep you dont need any custom view, just provide your background Drawable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create CustomEditText that extends EditText , code is bellow :

```
public class MyCustomEditText extends EditText {

private Rect mRect;
private Paint mPaint;

public MyCustomEditText (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mRect = new Rect();
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    int aColor = Color.parseColor("#dedede");
    mPaint.setColor(aColor);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    int height = getHeight();
    int line_height = getLineHeight();
    int count = height / line_height;
    if(getLineCount() > count){
        count = getLineCount();
    }
    Rect r = mRect;
    Paint paint = mPaint;
    int baseline = getLineBounds(0, r);
    for (int i = 0; i < count-1; i++) {
        canvas.drawLine(r.left, baseline + 1, r.right, baseline + 1, paint);
        baseline += getLineHeight();
    }
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

In xml, put your new CustomEditText instead of EditText

Comment: How can i used it xml..? simple when i used EditText just Replace with CustomEditText

Comment: yes, instead of using <EditText .... /> , you will use <your.pacakge.name.MyCustomEditText ... />  you can use all standard xml tags like you are using standard EditText. 
The comments above are about using background image so it looks like line, but my code will draw underline for every line of text you need, if you have 10 lines of text, you will have 10 lines underlying them, if you have just one, only one line will be drawn, it even works if you press enter to create new lines, they will be drawn.

Comment: its code working fine but how can i hide default edittext background underline

Comment: you can just use xml tag  android:background="#00000000" and it should remove it

Comment: android:paddingLeft="15dp" , of course you can use any number you want instead of 15. If you liked the answer, please accept it :)

Comment: when i used paddingLeft, the EditText take padding not text...i want to give space to text, not give sapce to edittext

Comment: i don't know how to align text only, padding worked fine for me

Comment: after pressing enter, the cursor is not aligning to baseline. I want the cursor to align baseline after pressing enter. How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

you should to try

[Holo Every where](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere)