# match_parent doesn't fit to desired results

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I am new to `Android` and I am designing a layout. In my layout I have an `EditText` in the top and after that I want an attractive underline. So I design an narrow image line and I have set it under the bottom of `EditText`. I have set its left and right padding and then I have set the `ImageView` to `match_parent`. My problem is I am getting the perfect result in some of the `Android` devices but in some devices the `ImageView` is shown centered or to the right of `EditText`. I have tried all possible solutions but still it is giving me same result. Please help me. I am trying to solve it for so many hours. My code is as below:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.app.HomeActivity"
android:background="@drawable/za">
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:alpha="0.5"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:ems="14"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:hint="@string/str_hint"
    android:textColorHint="#F3FFFF" >
    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:alpha="0.5"    
    android:src="@drawable/white_line" />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    android:alpha="0.5"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:ems="14"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:hint="Enter Password"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:textColorHint="#F3FFFF" />
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:alpha="0.5"
    android:src="@drawable/white_line" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

**Image**:

[image]

Comment: Try removing all the paddings.

Comment: Still narrow line is centered.. When i focus on the imageview a light green line shows that it is set to fill entire screen.. but when i remove the mouse focus still narrow line is centered.

Comment: is these any other way i can underline the edittext and make it look attractive? i mean also set its alpha property.?

Comment: Can you post an image to see what is your expected result? add an url if you dont have  enough reputation.

Comment: May this link <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22195770/how-to-design-custom-edittext-without-box-and-with-underline> could help you.

Comment: <com.example.app.MyCustomEditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:ems="14"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:hint="@string/str_hint"
        
        android:textColorHint="#F3FFFF" 
        
 /> I have followed the above link but it is not showing underline

Comment: @PratibhaSharma I have followed your link but it is not showing underline.. 
<com.example.app.MyCustomEditText android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" android:alpha="0.5" android:background="@android:color/transparent" android:ems="14" android:textSize="20sp" android:hint="@string/str_hint" android:textColorHint="#F3FFFF" />

Comment: @FrankN.Stein
  http://i.stack.imgur.com/4G0bf.png

Result is still the same as shown

Comment: You still make confusion about when to use `@+id` and when to use `@id`

Comment: If you found my answer useful, could you accept it? ;)

Answer (score 0):

This may be because of the image resolution. Using `match_parent` therefore does not guarantee that your image will fit, especially in larger devices.

However, using some of the [`android:scaleType`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) attributes on your `ImageView` can stretch the image to fit the content as you want it. For example, the `android:scaleType="fitCenter"` should scale the image and centre it.